# Select additional information with Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, dao, hibernate-criteria

I have following code:

```
session
    .createCriteria(MyObj.class)
    .add(Restrictions.
             sqlRestriction("1=1 CONNECT BY conn_by = PRIOR id START WITH id = ?", 
                                 id, Hibernate.LONG)).list();
```

This code works however I want to select also `level` information (used with `connect_by` in Oracle). How I can select also this value? I do not consider `level` information as part of the `MyObj` class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate criteria will return only information that is available in `MyObj.class` ...according to you if your class don't have level info then it will give you error